# Compare String values in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure which is called from a program. This stored procedure is passed 2 names and needs to find similar names in the database. However when I try to compare - 'AFC Bournemouth' with the name in the db which is 'Bournemouth'.

```
    bet.searchFixtureForResult 
    @homeTeam NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @awayTeam NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @date DATE
AS
    SELECT fixtureId 
    FROM bet.fixture 
    WHERE homeTeam IN (SELECT teamId 
                       FROM bet.team 
                       WHERE team LIKE '%' + @homeTeam + '%')
      AND awayTeam IN (SELECT teamId 
                       FROM bet.team 
                       WHERE team LIKE '%' + @awayTeam + '%') 
      AND fixtureDate = @date
```

This supposedly returns the Id of the fixture that falls within the parameters given. How can compare similar strings such that I compare in the same way you compare with `.Contains` in C#?

Comment: Use [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need `bet.team` there at all, your query will be like

```
SELECT fixtureId 
FROM bet.fixture
WHERE (HomeTeam LIKE '%' + @HomeTeam + '%' OR @HomeTeam LIKE '%' + HomeTeam + '%')
      AND
      (AwayTeam LIKE '%' + @AwayTeam + '%' OR @AwayTeam LIKE '%' + AwayTeam + '%')
      AND
      fixtureDate = @date;
```

Here is a little **[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=eefb4ea876db0ef3f1218aa6cf1a9f00)**